# Canvas Page https //www.facebook.com/4oh4.php

Tags: url, canvas, facebook-apps

Hi I am new to Facebook dev, I have some experience with javascript/php/mysql so I am positive I can scrape through this lol.

I have set up my app on facebook

App ID/API Key
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

My site URL
https //www.glamit.co.uk

Canvas Page
https //apps.facebook.com/246606452042055/

App Secret
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Secure Canvas URL
https //www.glamit.co.uk/bla/bla/bla/

Site Domain
www.glamit.co.uk

Canvas URL
http //apps.facebook.com/glamit/

Canvas FBML/iframe
iframe

My app is stored on a SSL server Secure Canvas URL
https //www.glamit.co.uk/bla/bla/bla/

but when I try this in my browser http://apps.facebook.com/glamit/ I get "The page you requested was not found.
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive."

https //www.facebook.com/4oh4.php

I had to miss : out http: because it wouldn't let me post

Comment: Hey What kind of app are you setting this up for?. I did the App on Facebook option and it worked for me with setting the canvas url to https://www.glamit.co.uk/ . Usually you get 404 page if there is any issue with the configuration of the app. Here is a working example https://apps.facebook.com/sftestapps/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I just landed here so figured I'd let y'all know what fixed my problem. I was landing on the 4oh4 page when I'd log out of my app using the PHP sdk.

Well, my app was in sandbox mode, which means it's only available to developers. When I logged out of FB, obviously FB had no way of knowing I was the dev, hence it threw the 4oh4, which is expected behavior.

As soon as I logged in, I was able to access the page. To validate, I removed it from sandbox mode and sure enough, when I logged out, I was directed to the proper page.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "bookmark" property in the advanced app settings to the desired URL.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I have set the bookmark url to  http://apps.facebook.com/glamit/ and I still get the same error